# How to bypass Google recaptcha in a form using Mechanize

Tags: python, python-requests, recaptcha, mechanize

I need to fill a form on a webpage and bypass its captcha.
using [this library](https://github.com/AdminAnticaptcha/anticaptcha-python) I'm able to solve the captcha and get g-recaptcha-response stored in a variable. now the question is, how to pass the validation token to the form using Mechanize?

here's my half-baked code:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0")]
url = "https://removedforprivacyreasons.com"
response = br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.find_control("consentGivenPP").items[0].selected=True
br.form['email'] = fullemailaddr
br.form['firstName'] = randomstring
br.form['lastName'] = randomstring
br.form['company'] = 'CloudFlare'
br.submit()
```

I tried using

```
br.form['g-recaptcha-response'] = g_response
```

but I guess that is not the correct way.